# jQueryUI's blockUI blocking unappropriately

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm making an e-commerce webapplication(in MVC3) and right now I'm testing it. My problem is: Whenever someone clicks many times on submit buttons, I make as many requests and save it on db as many times also. So I'm implementing some client-side and server-side code to prevent these multiple submits. The client-side consists in blocking screen whenever someone clicks on a submit button like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
        blockScreen();
    });

    $.unblockUI();
}
function blockScreen() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="../images/processing.gif" /></h1>' 
});
```

**The problem I am having with blockUI is when someone clicks a submit but there is a ModelState error (such as non-filled required field) the screen is blocked and can't be unblocked unless reloaded or with browser's console**.

The server-side validation so it won't have replication I'll do later, so no need to consider it for this question...

Comment: Why don't you block the screen from your model's code, i.e. only when sending the request (and of course removing it when a result is there)?

Comment: call the function blockScreen() when the validation true.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean block screen from model's code?

Comment: I wouldn't block the whole screen unless that is in fact what you want to do, instead maybe just disable the button for a few seconds or more. It seems like the problem isn't with the javascript though, unless by adding the html it throws off the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to it... following krish's advice, I added this script:

`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` to my master view and used this on my js:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        blockScreen();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using AJAX request to send data to your database, right?

No need to use the 'click' event.
Someone can submits the form by just pressing Enter inside an input field and i'm not sure in this case a click event is fired.

I think you suould use something like that:

```
var isBlocked = false;

$('form').submit(function(){

  $.ajax({
    url: 'database.html',
    beforeSend: function (data) {
       var state = isBlocked;
       isBlocked = true;
       // Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request.
       return !state;
    },
    complete: function(data) {
       // complete executes on both success and fail
       isBlocked = false;
    }
  });


});
```

`